# Mysql replication: Will this INSERT statement be captured into the binary logs?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a small doubt in mysql replication. If an insert failed with duplicate alert error on master server be captured into the binary logs or it be ignored and not replicated on the salve.

If it captured, is there a mechanism to stop it on the master side itslef ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on a test machine. failed transactions on master due to key or constraint errors are not being logged into binary logs.

```
Here is how i tested

    Created a test innodb table (id primary key, name)
    Inserted a row and checked the bin log size
    Inserted another row with same id value and it failed with duplicate alert.
    Now checked the log size and there is no change in size.
```

Thanks

Even verified the binlog with mysqlbinlog utility.... :)